# Why shell report "command not found" while using cat?

Tags: shell

I'm processing a file by line, so my shell script is this:

```
check_vm_connectivity()
{
    $res=`cat temp.txt` # this is line 10
    i=0

    for line in "$res"
    do
        i=$i+1
        if [[ $i -gt 3 ]] ; then
            continue
        fi
        echo "${line}"
    done
}
```

The temp.txt is this:

```
+--------------------------------------+
| ID                                   |
+--------------------------------------+
| cb91a52f-f0dd-443a-adfe-84c5c685d9b3 |
| 184564aa-9a7d-48ef-b8f0-ff9d51987e71 |
| f01f9739-c7a7-404c-8789-4e3e2edf314e |
| 825925cc-a816-4434-8b4b-a75301ddaefd |
```

when I run script, report this:

```
vm_connectivity.sh: line 10: =+--------------------------------------+: command not found
```

Why? How to fix this bug? Thank you~

Answer (score 2):

May i ask why you are using

```
$res=`cat temp.txt`?
```

shouldn't it be

```
res=`cat temp.txt`
```

Answer (score 1):

variables in a shell are set with `var=` rather than `$var=`

res is empty when you're entering the function, so that line
expands to the empty string, followed by an equals sign,
followed by the contents of temp.txt.  The shell then interprets
that, and since a command is terminated by a newline, and
`=+--------------------------------------+` has the syntax
of a command, rather than anything else, the shell tries to
run it as such.

You want: `res=$(cat temp.txt)`

However, it looks like you're trying to output 
the first three lines, in which case just
do

```
head -n3 temp.txt
```

though from the looks of it, you probably want all except the first three
lines:

```
tail -n +4 temp.txt
```

and if you're looking for just the uuids:

```
tail -n +4 temp.txt | awk '{print $2}'
```